# Remove span when text inside the span is changed in Android

Tags: java, android, html

Let´s say I make a comment like this:
Hi Andrea check this out..... In that comment I want to highlight Andrea, but whenever I change the value of Andrea or when I delete one character of the word the span changes, the problem is that I´m using `spannableString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), indexOfAt, highlightName.length() + indexOfAt, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)`, which `Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` accepts words in the middle and deletion of words, how can I remove the span when the user changes the word or delete a character of the word?

Comment: A fiddle or code will be helpful to answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to watch for Text change on the edit text.
Assuming the `EditText`, you are using is named as `commentEditText`

```
 commentEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String comment = editable.toString();
                if (comment.indexOf('@') != -1) {
                    //Asumming the name string
                    String name = "Andrea";
                    int atIndex = comment.indexOf('@');
                    int endIndex = atIndex + name.length() + 1;
                    if (endIndex == -1 || endIndex > editable.length()) {
                        endIndex = editable.length();
                    }
                    if (comment.toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
                        editable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), atIndex, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    } else {
                        StyleSpan[] spannable = editable.getSpans(atIndex, endIndex, StyleSpan.class);
                        if (spannable != null && spannable.length > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < spannable.length; i++) {
                                editable.removeSpan(spannable[i]);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `SpannableString` you have to recreate the whole thing on every change.

You can remove spans but you cannot change the source (the comment) because `SpannableString` source text is immutable.

I suggest on every change of the comment you create the `SpannableString`, look for names and tag them, then if the comment changes you repeat the same thing with a new `SpannableString`. There will be no performance problems because the comments are small in size.

If you want to have a mutable object you can use the `SpannableStringBuilder` but it's more complicated and there is no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try TextWatcher for this, simply add TextWatcher to the textview you want to achieve above and in on

```
 @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
//Do some magic here
    }
```

Now whenever user types or deletes any character you will get a callback in this method upon receiving that you can reset your span.

Comment: explained the basic idea was to get a callback for text change which is achieved here.